# Issues with using R's bizdays package to create weekdays calendar for daily stock prices data

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have data on daily stock prices from Brazil span over the period 2000-01-03/2018-11-15, the data contain working days only, therefore, I'm using bizdays package to create calendar counting working days and skips weekends, bizdays requires predefined calendar to adjust dates to working days. To this end, we can use RQunatLib or Rmetrics to load the calendar we want. Once we get the calendar of interest, we can adjust dates to working days only with following code:

```
dates <- bizdays(from='2000-01-03', to='2018-11-15', cal)
```

In my case which is Brazil, to get the calendar I used the following codes:

```
install.packages("bizdays")
require(bizdays)
install.packages("RQuantLib")
require(RQuantLib)
load_quantlib_calendars('Brazil', from='2000-01-03', to='2018-11-15')
```

The problem here is that function "load_quantlib_calendars" is not recognized

```
Error in load_quantlib_calendars("Brazil", from = "2000-01-03", to = "2018-11-15") :
could not find function "load_quantlib_calendars"
```

Why is the function not working?

Comment: lubridate wday function is very easier than this have a look 
lubridate::wday(date, label = TRUE)  . Also your spelling is wrong for bizdays while loading the library. require(bizdays)

Comment: @ Hunaidkhan Thanks, I'm already reading an article about "lubridate", I'll try it for sure. Btw the spelling mistake has bee corrected

Comment: @Hunaidkhan zoo is also very useful in this case and fairly easy to use, I created date index "X" using the code `X <- seq( as.Date("2000/1/03"), as.Date("2018/11/15"),"days")`, then excluded the weekend days from the date index "X" by doing this `weekdays.X <- X[ ! weekdays(X) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")]`. I got new date index without weekends "weekdays.X". lastly I combined the new date index with my stock price time series "SPrices1": `XPrices = zoo(x=SPrices1, order.by=weekdays.X)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This should do the work for you***

```
days <- as.data.frame(as.Date(seq(as.Date("2000-01-03"), as.Date("2018-11-15"), by="days")))
    colnames(days)<- c("Date")

    days$condition <- lubridate::wday(days$Date, label = TRUE)
```

**If you want to remove weekend from the data use the below code**

```
days_new <- mutate(days, Date = wday(Date, label = T)) %>%
  filter(Date != "Sat", Date != "Sun")
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, it works great, now how can I attach the new object "days_new" to my stock price time series

Comment: you can do left join or you can directly use this data for time series analysis